# Add line break on label

Tags: jfreechart

I am using `CategoryPointerAnnotation` to draw an arrow and show label. Right now the label seems to be too wide. Is it possible to add a line break so that that $ amount shows up on the next line?

```
CategoryPointerAnnotation ann5 = new CategoryPointerAnnotation("You are here $" +
    NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(
        num.intValue()), cat, num.intValue(), -2.35619449);
```

[image]

Comment: Trim the annotation, and use a tool tip for the full text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, line-breaks are **not supported**. Neither in title, subtitles, labels, tooltips, etc. You can search the [JFreeChart forum](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=3) for "linebreak" or "newline" to find related posts. There have been featuers-requests and according to the forum there were even patches available to fix this, but none has made it into JFreeChart yet (as of 1.0.19).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding in System.getProperty("line.separator")?

Comment: "You are here $"+System.getProperty("line.separator")+ NumberFormat..... Are you saying this? I tried this, but no luck

Comment: That was the idea, but clearly a dud. Might be possible to create a string using that same code and using ann5.settext(yourString) though instead of passing the string to the constructor.